# Django Success_url

Tags: django, django-forms

I built a FormView with two fields in it.  I want to use the form to pass queries to a view.

```
class SectorForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField()
    days = forms.IntegerField(max_value=365, min_value=1)
```

Is there a way I can take my FormView and build the **success_url** from the valid form fields?

So overriding the get_success_url.

```
      def get_success_url(self): 
        return reverse_lazy('queryable-view' date days)
```

I thought I could pull it out from form_valid but never had success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_success_url` doesn't have access to the `Form` instance, but `form_valid` does. Try something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class YourFormView(FormView):
    # ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        date, days = form.cleaned_data['date'], form.cleaned_data['days']
        return redirect('queryable-view', date, days)
```

Comment: Thanks!!  That worked.  I ended up using `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('queryable-view', args=(date.strftime("%Y%m%d"), days)))`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem once. When you work with forms, you may not use kwargs and get_success_url doesn't have access to the Form (as told before)
I have get around as:

```
class YourView(CreateView):
appointment_id =0

def form_valid(self,form):
    appointment = form.save()
    self.appointment_id = appointment.pk
    print self.appointment_id

    return super(AppointmentCreate,self).form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
    if  kwargs != None:
        return reverse_lazy('payment', kwargs = {'appid': self.appointment_id})
```